# Any way to control the order of directories for LoadTypeLibEx similar to LoadLibraryEx?

Tags: windows, winapi

I have the following problem. In my program, I call LoadTypeLibEx with a full path:

```
ITypeLib* m_pTypeLib = nullptr;
LoadTypeLibEx(L"C:\\exepath\\MyLib.tlb", REGKIND_NONE, &m_pTypeLib);
```

But if I start the exe from a different directory, *"C:\otherdir"* with a shortcut and I copy *MyLib.tlb* to *C:\otherdir*, then *Procmon* shows me that `LoadTypeLibEx` loads *MyLib.tlb* from *"C:\otherdir"* even though I give the full explicit path *"C:\exepath\MyLib.tlb"*.

Has anyone else encountered this issue?

Comment: The system keeps typelibs in cache. Are you sure it wasn't loaded before you call LoadTypeLibEx

Comment: After moving the code to a minimal sample I realized the issue was actually coming from a call to `IActiveScript::AddTypeLib` and not from `LoadTypeLibEx`.But the type library should already be cached, shouldn't it?

Comment: My suspicion is that LoadTypeLibEx does not touch the cache (either for lookup or storage). Usually, I use RegisterTypeLibForUser for typelibs I'm going to feed to ActiveScript.

Comment: IActiveScript::AddTypeLib will call LoadRegTypeLib https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/oleauto/nf-oleauto-loadregtypelib so it will not use paths but registry.